# How to create an eml file as outlook draft email with django EmailMessage?

Tags: django, email, outlook, msg, eml

I'm looking for an email as a draft.
I would like to double click on later draft and send it via outlook.
Currently, I am able to create the eml file and open it in outlook on double click. However, I cannot send it.
Can you help me please, I spent a week above but without success.

**Here is the code:**

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
@login_required
def Envoi_Mail(request):
    date_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    id_path = request.GET.get('id_path')
    dossier_media = str(settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    msg = EmailMessage(
        'Bonjour',
        'Test test tes',
        'from@abc.com',
        ['to@abc.com'],
    )
    content_text = msg.message().as_bytes()
    file_name = dossier_media + "/" + str(date_now) + ".eml"
    with open(file_name, "wb") as outfile:
        outfile.write(content_text)
    return redirect(id_path)
```

**Here is what I get:**

[image]

**Here is what I would like to have:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you add `X-Unsent: 1` MIME header.

Comment: Thank you so much. it works. I addes headers={'X-Unsent':  '1'}, in msg = EmailMessage(). Is there a better way?

Comment: A better way? I don't think so. But why is adding the header a problem?